# Comparation Periods in Google Data Studio

Tags: looker-studio

I'm creating a in google data studio that has a table behind with data by day.
I need it to be comparable with the month before, but there's a catch that I'm currently stuck!

The period should be something like:

> DAY(date)/MONTH(date)-1/YEAR(date)

This allows the comparation between periods with different number of days, example:

> Date of analysis: 28/06/2021 - 27/07/2021
> Date of comparation: 28/05/2021 - 27/06/2021

When trying to create something like this in DataStudio (with date range controls) none of the options does this, and for what I've explored, there isn't an option to do a formula like the one above.
The closest I get is "Previous Period" but that makes the Date of Comparation 29/05/2021 - 27/06/2021, missing the 28/05/2021.

I'm really stuck and running out of ideas, I've even considered changing the SQL query behind to convert the days somehow.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Data Studio: Different fixed, dynamically-generated date ranges for each metric column in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72903152/google-data-studio-different-fixed-dynamically-generated-date-ranges-for-each)

Answer (score 0):

I've done this by mocking the dates for the comparator.

The other way is to create two series, and don't use the comparator.

Series #1 will have label 28/06/2021 and data from 28/06/2021 (current period).
Series #2 will have label 28/06/2021 (the same) and data from 28/05/2021 (previous period).

They plot nicely:

[image]