# Google Data Studio: Different fixed, dynamically-generated date ranges for each metric column in a table

Tags: looker-studio

I have a [Google Data Studio table](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/dbf26dc2-175a-4c7c-a2c9-73fd998376b4) where the data range for the entire table is set using a control. It looks like this:

| Page | Unique Views (after 7 days) | Unique Views (after 30 days) | Unique Views (after 90 days) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| /page1.html | 9 | 9 | 9 |
| /page2.html | 7 | 7 | 7 |
| /page3.html | 7 | 7 | 7 |

But I'm trying to set a different date range for each Unique Pageviews column, so the data would look like this:

| Page | Unique Views (after 7 days) | Unique Views (after 30 days) | Unique Views (after 90 days) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| /page1.html | 9 | 32 | 101 |
| /page2.html | 7 | 14 | 76 |
| /page3.html | 7 | 21 | 37 |

I see how to set the date range at the report/control/table level ([docs](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6291067?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article)), but I haven't found a way to set the date range at the table column level.

Am I missing something or is this simply a limitation of Data Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to perform a [blend](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9061420) with three tables (all from the same data source, in this scenario the [sample Google Analytics](https://datastudio.google.com/u/0/datasources/fd360d67-5fbf-4591-8e72-b2e56ea47df8) data source), but each with a different custom date range, one for each [date range](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6291067) required (7 days, 30 days and 90 days); each date range will be dynamic, shifting automatically, daily:

### 1) Blend

| Table 1 | Table 2 | Table 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ***Dimension***: `Page` | ***Dimension***: `Page` | ***Dimension***: `Page` |
| ***Metric***: `Unique Views` ***Rename*** with suffix `(after 90 days)` [image: calc_field_90_days] | ***Metric***: `Unique Views` ***Rename*** with suffix `(after 30 days)` [image: calc_field_30_days] | ***Metric***: `Unique Views` ***Rename*** with suffix `(after 7 days)` [image: calc_field_7_days] |
| ***Date Range***: Custom (Advanced - Last 90 Days) [image: daterange_90days] | ***Date Range***: Custom (Last 30 Days) [image: daterange_30days] | ***Date Range***: Custom (Last 7 Days) [image: daterange_7days] |
| [image: blend_table_1] | [image: blend_table_2] | [image: blend_table_2] |

### 2) Join Configuration

| Join Description | Table 1 Table 2 | Table 1 Table 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Join Operator** | Left Outer | Left Outer |
| **Join Condition** | `Page (Table 1)` `Page (Table 2)` | `Page (Table 1)` `Page (Table 3)` |
| **Image** | [image: table1_table2] | [image: table1_table2] |

To summarise, the blend will be:

[image: blend_summary]

### 3) [Table](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7189044) (Chart)

- ***Data Source***: Blend
- ***Dimension***: `Page`
- ***Metric 1***: `Unique Views (after 7 days)`
- ***Metric 2***: `Unique Views (after 30 days)`
- ***Metric 3***: `Unique Views (after 90 days)`

Publicly editable [Google Data Studio](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/77172d4b-b95f-4b7c-8970-b2436de8ac98) report ([sample Google Analytics](https://datastudio.google.com/u/0/datasources/fd360d67-5fbf-4591-8e72-b2e56ea47df8) data source) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image: gif]